# How can I write a test in this case?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-7, mockery

P.S.:
At first I asked how to mock Model::create, but what I wanted to do was to write a test that would correctly go into the catch when an error occurred in the try.

Thanks to @matiaslauriti's comment, I found a better way, so I will change my question from how to mock to how to write tests.

Please see the answer section and comments for details.

・・・・・・・・

I have this code.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function addRecord()
    {
        //...

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                self::create([
                    'name'         => $name,
                    'phone'         => '',
                ]);
            }

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollback();

            throw($e);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my test code.but The mock returns an error and the test doesn't work.

```
class MyModelTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->my_model = new MyModel();

    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function addRecord_error()
    {
        $mock = \Mockery::mock(MyModel::class)->makePartial();
        $mock->shouldReceive('create')
　　　　　　->once()
          ->andThrow(new \Exception());

        $this->app->bind(MyModel::class, function () use ($mock) {
            return $mock;
        });

　　　　　$my_model = app(MyModel::class);

        //run method
        $my_model->addRecord();  

        // ↑↑ This return error with 
              //BadMethodCallException:Static method 
              //Mockery_2_App_Models_MyModel::addRecord() does not exist on this mock object

        //try {
           //$my_model->addRecord();

        //} catch (\Exception $ex) {

          // $this->assertCount(0, MyModel::all());
        //}
    }
}
```

I would like to write a test where if the try fails, it goes to catch and rollback is called.

Comment: First of all, you are using `new MyModel();`, you are never going to get a `mock` that way as you are literally using `new`, so you are creating a new instance... what you have to do is use `app(MyModel::class);` or `resolve(MyModel::class);` (`resolve` is an alias of `app`). You have to use any of these helpers after you have declare the expectation (after `shouldReceive->....->....`) and use `$this->app->bind(MyModel::class, $mock)`, not `$this->instance`. You can also have "better" code for the first part: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions

Comment: @matiaslauriti  Thank you for your comment ! I tried changing the code as above, but I am getting an error and it seems to not have gone through the mock yet. Is there anything else I should do?
Thanks for the better code too. I can't change the product method since I'm only in charge of testing, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Let me add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test code should look like this:

```php
use Exception;
use Mockery\Mockery;

class MyModelTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function addRecord_error()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock(MyModel::class)->makePartial();
        $mock->shouldReceive('create')
　　　　　　->once()
          ->andThrow(new Exception);

        $my_model = app(MyModel::class);

        try {
            $my_model::addRecord();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
           $this->assertCount(0, Model::all());
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using the model inside itself, you must add the mock to the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations) before [`app`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-app) helper function:

```php
$this->app->bind(MyModel::class, function () use ($mock) {
    return $mock;
});
```

Have in mind that `$this->assertCount(0, Model::all());` should be replaced with the Model you want to test if it was rolled back. So replace `Model` with the desired `Model`.

But, that should pass all the time, as you are throwing the error the first time it is run, so you are never adding anything. So `assertCount` should always pass, and if you remove it or not, is the same.

Comment: Thank you again and again.

I rewrote the method as above, but it returns the error "does not exist on this mock object".

1:create Mock
2:$this->app->bind...
3:app(MyModel::class)
4: run test method

Is the order correct?
Sorry for asking so many questions..

Comment: Ask as many questions as you need to, no worries about that. Can you share here the full error please?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
The error is "Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Static method Mockery_2_App_Models_MyModel::addRecord() does not exist on this mock object". 
The message in $exception returned the same error, so I tried calling the function outside of try catch and got this error.
(I have modified the original question to the current code)

Comment: I have no idea what is going on, as you did not share the full code. But still, this should not be tested like this. I know this is a ticket you have from your company, but it is harder to test what you want to test. Why would the `create` throw an error? Is the DB an external DB?

Comment: > Is the DB an external DB? It is not an external DB.I wrote the test code as I asked, because I want to test that when an error occurs in the try, it goes into the catch and the DB is rolled back to normal. If you don't mind, could you please tell me what you mean by "this should not be tested like this"? I would like to be able to write the tests that I should.

Comment: Yes sir, let me explain: when we write a test, we want to test a case. In this example you want to test if the data is rolled back if an error occurs, the issue with this test is there is no clear case why would that happened, that is why this is so hard to come up with something to mock. Some cases that now comes to mind are: DB connection failed, or your DB user/pass was not authorized to use the DB, or the data you are inserting (create method) is duplicate so you need a column to be unique and you send that data again. Appart from that, there is no clear case why would it fail.

Comment: I changed the mock target to the DB you mentioned in your example, and was able to reproduce the condition going into the catch as desired! > why would that happened, I hadn't thought of that at all (I was just thinking of raising an error to get into the catch). Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Glad I was of help. Remember that when you want to test something, you have to think in the pre-condition and then in what case should happen for this test to test. You were able to understand that and create a test that tests what you wanted to test, that is the thinking you have to apply all the time.

Comment: It hasn’t been long since I started writing tests, so I feel each test is difficult.. but I
 will create tests with what you taught me in mind. Thank you very much!!